# Can I use 'make the disabilities able'?

Tags: usage

> I want to be a neurological surgeon who make the disabilities able.

The question I have is about whether I can use "make the disabilities able" to describe that I want to reconnect the patients' nerves and make them stand up as they wish.

Comment: The antonym of *disable* is *enable* but that won't work here (as a replacement for *able*.) You could use something like "I want to be a neurological surgeon and cure people's disabilities."

Comment: You want to *reverse* their disabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, don't say it like this. While your sentence is grammatical (with the exception of the conjugation: *surgeon* is singular, so it should be *make**s***), it's not semantic. *Disabilities* refers to the conditions or states, not the people themselves, so you're not making them *able*. Similarly, a surgeon operates on people, not their maladies. To keep the nice *disabled* / *able* juxtaposition, I'd phrase the sentence like this:

> I want to be a neurological surgeon who makes the disabled able.

Consider adding *again* to the end, to emphasize that you want to restore nerve function to people who had and previously lost it, if you want to narrow the meaning in that way. Your use of *reconnect* in the question suggests that you're searching for this particular nuance.

Comment: Not everyone who is disabled was ever able, I would suggest against "again" unless you really are operating only on people who have lost function.